# Internal Error in Firebase Analytics Console Dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, google-analytics

I just followed the `https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?authuser=0` to install Firebase Analytics in my Android app.
Also, I give some permissions like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in the manifest.
My current issue is I can see the in internal error when I click the Analytics Dashboard in the `console.firebase.google.com`.

[image: issue]

Also, I can't see any events even I log event like this.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("ButtonID", v.getId());
params.putString("ButtonName", "MigraineButton");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, params);
```

P.S: Also, I tried to open this dashboard in the chrome ignitor or firefox.

Please teach me what is the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We've confirmed a bug on our end with regard to granting the user access to the Firebase Analytics Dashboard for some accounts. We're now working on a fix, but don't have any timelines yet on when the fix will be available. For now, as a workaround, `can you ask an owner of the project to grant you access to the Analytics report from the Google Analytics console`? Once access has been granted from GA, you should be able to access the Firebase Analytics Dashboard.
Apologies for the inconvenience. For further updates on the bug, you can check our release notes.**

I contacted the firebase support team and I get this message from the firebase support team.

I get this issue because my client didn't grant Google Analytics console access to me. So you need to grant Google Analytics console access too to solve this problem.
Thank you.